# Sum two counts in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a question, I am building up a query.

```
select top 10 usr.firstname, usr.lastname, count(doc.modifiedBy) as modified_items,
       count(doc.createdDate) as created_items 
from document doc
where doc.active = 't' 
group by usr.firstname, usr.lastname
order by doc.modified_items desc
```

But I want to sum two counts that are in select so something like this.

```
select top 10 usr.firstname, usr.lastname, sum(count(doc.modifiedBy), count(doc.createdDate))
```

Comment: Dear, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You mean like `count(doc.modifiedBy) + count(doc.createdDate)`?

Comment: @Chris that won't work.

Comment: Note that if you add them using + then records with both a modified date and a created date will be counted twice. This may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple just add `+` them.

```
SELECT TOP 10 usr.firstname, usr.lastname, count(doc.modifiedBy) AS modified_items, count(doc.createdDate) AS created_items, (count(doc.modifiedBy)) + (count(doc.createdDate)) AS summed_items
FROM document doc
WHERE doc.active = 't' 
GROUP BY usr.firstname, usr.lastname
ORDER BY doc.modified_items DESC
```